# NodeList returning undefined? Function inside window.onload

Tags: javascript

So I'm currently building a carousel (code inspired from W3Schools).

```
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");


    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");

    }

    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    changeShoeContent(slideIndex-1);
  }
```

This code is inside a window.onload function. The slideshow works, and everything, but for some reason, whenever I try to console.log dots or slides, its returning undefined. The slideshow works, which means that the for loop is able to change the display and class names of the slides and dots nodeList. Am I doing something wrong here, or am I missing something?

Comment: where do you use console.log? put the complete code of the wrong place

Comment: I tested with carousel W3School [link example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow) and It shows me the data when I write `console.log(slides)` or with dots It seem that works ok, can you write a jsfiddle?